# Discord.js | guild.iconURL not working in embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to show the server's icon in the `serverinfo` embed, but it won't show up.

```js
var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL;
const serverInfoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('server info')
  .setColor(0x348a58)
  .addField('owner', message.guild.owner, true)
  .addField('name', '`' + message.guild.name + '`', true)
  .addField('members', '`' + message.guild.memberCount + '`', true)
  .setThumbnail(serverIcon)
  .setFooter('very bootiful server');

setTimeout(() => { message.channel.send(serverInfoEmbed) }, 200);
console.log(serverIcon);
```

in the console, it says:

```
[Function: iconURL]
```

I tried to put it directly as the thumbnail `.setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL)` but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `guild.iconURL()` is a function, and you would need to replace your line :

```
var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL;
```

with :

```
var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL();
```

I also suggest you to [read the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=iconURL) for more info :)

Comment: thanks! if the docs and stack overflow weren't there, I wouldn't be able to build my bot lol

Comment: @FrancescoGatta No problem, we're here to help ! :3